# How to Update two tables Having foreign key relationship using single post request - asp.net mvc web api

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I have created one asp.net mvc web api using Entity framework model, Which can update Single table in Single request. What i want is to update two tables(Having foreign key relationship) in single POST Request.

How I can achieve this?

What I have Done:-

1.Created Two Table **tblEmployeeRecord** & **tblCountryName** in sql server with EmployeeId as a primary key & foreign key respectively.
2.Employee table Model:-

```
public partial class tblEmployeeRecord
    {
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string userName { get; set; }
        public string userRole { get; set; }
    }
```

3.Country Name table Model:-

```
public partial class tblCountryName
    {
        public int CountryId { get; set; }
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public string Country_Name { get; set; }
       }
```

4.Created wrapper Model as follow:-

```
 public class UserAndCountry
    {
        public tblEmployeeRecord UserRecord { get; set; }
        public tblCountryName CountryRecord { get; set; }
    }
```

5.ActionResult Method in Controller Which handles post request:-

```
[ResponseType(typeof(UserAndCountry))]
        public IHttpActionResult PosttblEmployeeRecord(UserAndCountry tblEmployeeRecord)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }
            db.tblCountryNames.Add(tblEmployeeRecord.CountryRecord);
            db.tblEmployeeRecords.Add(tblEmployeeRecord.UserRecord);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = tblEmployeeRecord.UserRecord.EmployeeId }, tblEmployeeRecord);
        }
```

6.Note:-What is Happening:-  
 **When I don't define foreign key relationship in SQL Server between these two table, I am able to update both table but when i define foreign key relationship I am not able to update these tables**  
   **What will be my request object in that case, Where I am going wrong?** 
7.My Current Request object:-

```
{
    "CountryRecord":
{
        "Country_Name": "AP"
},
"UserRecord":
{

        "Name": "Test User",
        "userName": "Test.User@mail.com",
        "userRole": "Hr"
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, it is possible to update 10 tables in a single post request. Be more specific and clear, so that we can help you. Give at least an example of what you are trying to accomplish!

Comment: What's preventing you from updating more tables? Can you please post some sample code?

Comment: @Zhavat & Makotosan Updated My Question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The power of entity framework is the navigation properties for relationships. So say your models were:

```
public partial class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string userName { get; set; }
    public string userRole { get; set; }

    // Foreign Key
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    // Navigation Property
    public virtual Country EmployeeCountry
}

public partial class Country
{
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public string Country_Name { get; set; }
}
```

Now your update becomes:

```
var employeeRecord = tblEmployeeRecord.UserRecord;
// add the country. EF will make the relationship automagically
employeeRecord.EmployeeCountry = tblEmployeeRecord.CountryRecord;
db.Employees.Add(employeeRecord);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: But I have to Update both tables

Comment: This does update both tables. Best of all it also updates the foreign key too.